# MarshalXML for root element

Tags: xml, go, marshalling

I seem to be having a problem getting the marshaller to call `MarshalXML` for the root node. I have a struct for storing the XML like so:

```golang
type XmlNode struct {
    Name     string            `xml:"-"`
    Attrs    map[string]string `xml:"-"`
    Children []XmlNode         `xml:",any"`
}
```

I have a `MarshalXML` function like so:

```golang
func (n *XmlNode) MarshalXML(encoder *xml.Encoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    fmt.Println("Inside MarshalXML")

    // Name
    start.Name = xml.Name{Local: n.Name}

    // Attrs
    for k, v := range n.Attrs {
        start.Attr = append(start.Attr, xml.Attr{Name: xml.Name{Local: k}, Value: v})
    }

    type node XmlNode
    return encoder.EncodeElement((*node)(n), start)
}
```

And I'm calling it with code similar to:

```golang
func main() {
    root := XmlNode{Name: "root", Attrs: map[string]string{}}
    root.Attrs["rootAttr"] = "rootValue"

    child := XmlNode{Name: "child", Attrs: map[string]string{}}
    child.Attrs["childAttr"] = "childValue"

    root.Children = append(root.Children, child)
    out, _ := xml.Marshal(root)
    fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```

When it runs, I see the following output:

```
Inside MarshalXML
<XmlNode><child childAttr="childValue"></child></XmlNode>
```

I'm expecting:

```
Inside MarshalXML
Inside MarshalXML
<root rootAttr="rootValue"><child childAttr="childValue"></child></root>
```

I know that I can code the name into a specific attribute, but I'm more concerned with handling the attributes from a map. I'm also likely not supposed to be modifying the start element there, but it seems to work for this. My problem is that the MarshalXML doesn't get called for the root element, but it does for any children. So, even if I were to do something correctly there, I'm not sure I can intercept that root element to modify it appropriately.

I briefly tried using `xml.Encode` directly, but it seems to follow into the same path to build the start template and root, and then calls the `MarshalXML` for the `Children` node. Is there a clean way to get `XmlNode` converted into `xml.StartElement` so I can pass that in? I can write a function on XmlNode directly that'll start the marshalling by making a StartElement and calling `EncodeElement` or `Encode`, but I'm trying to avoid that and stick with the `xml.Marshal` call, to prevent some confusion for other devs.

Any thoughts?

Here's a [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Cl1FbF-FRa1) link to the above code in a runnable form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either pass in a pointer, i.e. `xml.Marshal(&root)` ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/3Z1TaMl_t8Y)), or change the receiver type from pointer to non-pointer, i.e. `func (n *XmlNode) MarshalXML` => `func (n XmlNode) MarshalXML` ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/8XBnwC0TowL)).

---

https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_sets

> The method set of type `T` consists of all methods declared
> with receiver type `T`. The method set of the corresponding pointer type
> `*T` is the set of all methods declared with receiver `*T` or `T` (that is, it also contains the method set of `T`).
>
> **The method set of a type determines the interfaces that the type
> implements and the methods that can be called using a receiver of that
> type.**

The above means that the variable `root`, which is of type `XmlNode`, DOES NOT implement `xml.Marshaler` *because* the `MarshalXML` method IS NOT part of `XmlNode`'s method set. However `&root`, which is of type `*XmlNode`, DOES implement `xml.Marshaler` *because* the `MarshalXML` method IS part of `*XmlNode`'s method set.

When you change the method's receiver to non-pointer, i.e. `func (n XmlNode) MarshalXML` then, `root`, which is of type `XmlNode`, will implement `xml.Marshaler` *because* the `MarshalXML` method will be part of `XmlNode`'s method set. And the cited spec also says that, `&root`, which is of type `*XmlNode` will also implement `xml.Marshaler` *because* the `MarshalXML` method, even though declared on `XmlNode`, will also be part of `*XmlNode`'s method set.

---

Note that this pointer vs non-pointer method set stuff is not so important to think about when you want to invoke a method on a concrete type directly as opposed to through an interface. For example if you have the variable `root` which if of type `XmlNode`, and you want to invoke the method `DoXyz`, which is declared with a pointer receiver as `func (n *XmlNode) DoXyz()`, then you DO NOT need `&root`, the expression `root.DoXyz` will compile just fine.

https://go.dev/ref/spec#Calls

> A method call `x.m()` is valid if the method set of (the type of) `x` contains `m` and the argument list can be assigned to the parameter list of `m`. **If `x` is addressable and `&x`'s method set contains `m`, `x.m()` is shorthand for `(&x).m()`**.

Comment: Perfect! I was certain I was missing something obvious. I come from C (and more recently C#), where implementing something was a tad more obvious (to me at least). But, I see the logic now and understand the implementation specifics more thanks to the articles you linked to.

I also appreciate the detailed explanation and information. So double kudos to you!